# Как работать с GPS во Fragment?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, пытаюсь запустить GPS, но не как не могу понять почему в созданном Fragment подчёркивает красным все this а так же getSystemService ?

```
public class GPS extends Fragment {


private LocationManager locationManager;

DBHelper dbHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000 * 10, 5, locationListener);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000*10, 5,
            locationListener);
}

@Override
public void onPause() { removeUpdates
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В  фрагменте нужно вот так:

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```